# Localized Values are not updating in Mongoose/Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, localization, mongoose-schema

This is an odd issue I have been seeing.  I have a mongoose schema using mongoose-i18n-localize:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongooseI18n = require('mongoose-i18n-localize');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TestSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  active: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  name: {type: String, required: true, i18n: true}
});

TestSchema.plugin(mongooseI18n, {
  locales: ['en_US']
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

In my call I have this:

```
app.put('/test/:id', function(req, res) {
  var query = {'id': req.params.id);
  var test = req.body;
  Test.findOneAndUpdate(query, test, function(err,p) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get information");
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(p);
    }
  })
});
```

and I passed in this data:

```
http://localhost:123/test/1d

{
  "active": true,
  "name": { "en_US": "test" }
}
```

I can change active to true and false with no issue.  But the name never changes when I make a change.  Also I get no error just does not update.  Has anyone seen this before or know how to fix this so I can do localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the body using dot notation instead of brackets. It worked for me in this way:

```
{
  "active": true,
  "name.en_US": "test"
}
```